# Re-designing an existing fireplace

Tags: fireplace

Can an amateur DIY'er re-design, demo, and built a new fireplace from an existing masonry fireplace?

- Tips and Tricks for following the building code
- Tips and Tricks for demo (how far to go)
- Tips and Tricks for replacing/adding a mantle

Comment: What exactly are you wanting to change/demo? Things like adding/replacing a mantel appear straight-forward enough but other work (especially chimney work) could be potentially dangerous and may require permits depending on your region.

Comment: I left the question rather open ended.  More this question is to find out how far a DIY'er to go in re-modeling a fireplace.

Comment: If you have a specific question, ask it. I think there are probably better forums to start an open ended chat about fireplaces in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am willing to tackle most DIY jobs in my house, but I, personally, would draw the line at the hearth/doors/mantel on this one.

I'm not willing to mess around inside the fire box or chimney of my fire place, nor with the gas lines or any masonry that is not part of the facade.  When I do have to work on stuff like that, I either bite the bullet and hire a licensed/insured professional, or at the very least, enlist help from a friend or family member with true professional experience.